# Keep 'tags' when importing Google Reader in Feedly

Tags: google-reader, feedly

As all regular Google Reader users know it's not going to be here for much longer. After looking around I've decided to change to use Feedly, which from what I can see seems to be the conclusion most people have come to.

At the moment I've got a lot of my 'page pulls' filed by using Google Reader's tag feature, but when I view my imported Google Reader feeds in Feedly they don't seem to be there. It gives me the option to tag stuff again, but there's two years of work saved in Google Reader tags. Any idea how I can get these showing up in Feedly?

Comment: Since this might be applicable to someone trying to import something else of this nature into Feedly, I'm going to leave this open for now.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of looking around I found the answer myself:

[Feedly blog: Migrating your tagged articles from Google Reader to feedly](http://blog.feedly.com/2013/04/24/migrating-your-tags-from-google-reader-to-feedly/)

Unfortunately it's not fully automated and you have retype some of them yourself.